# How to make build from iOS app when Team account missing?

Tags: xcode, swift, certificate, provisioning

I have installed new inHouse provisioning profiles, however when I archive my build in Xcode, I am presented with a message saying the iOS development team is missing. I have xcode 6.4. 
I know that you are able to build and sign an app if you don't have a developer team membership in Xcode.

Anyone know what is wrong?

Also another strange thing when I go into keychain to check if profiles and keys are there, they are not stored under the "Login" section like other profiles, but in "System". Is this ok?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to archive your build (either for the App Store or Adhoc) it must be codesigned by Xcode. This requires a signing identity. Signing identities are only obtainable through the developer console at http://developer.apple.com/ and requires being a member of the apple developer program to access.

Sorry to break the news but without a developer membership you won't be able to archive your app for a device, but run it in the simulator only.